# TikiWiki Login Error Message

Tags: wiki, tiki-wiki

I just finished installing Tiki Wiki on my server (standard Hostgator account), and was able to log in as an admin. I am trying to create a new file gallery, but I keep receiving this error when I fill out the gallery settings and hit the "Save" button:

Youre are not logged in. Go to the Log In Page.

Problem is, that doesn't make sense. How could I even access the admin interface to create a new file gallery if I wasn't logged in as an admin!?

Any ideas what's going on, and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Lukas

Comment: are your cookies on, if you are using any script related addons try to disable them first.

Comment: Seems your login session doesn't work properly. May I ask what Tiki version is that ? And do you see any errors in your Hostgator account error logs ?

Comment: Comment from @ricks99 posted as answer: Additional information would be helpful:
- What Tiki version?
- Are you storing Tiki session info in DB or File System?
- Did you turn on Tiki error reporting, and is anything shown?
- Are there any errors in your server log?
For best support, try the Tiki forums: http://tiki.org/forums

Answer (score 0):

Additional information would be helpful:
- What Tiki version?
- Are you storing Tiki session info in DB or File System?
- Did you turn on Tiki error reporting, and is anything shown?
- Are there any errors in your server log?
For best support, try the Tiki forums: http://tiki.org/forums

Comment: Hi ricks, this looks more like a comment than an answer. ;-)

Comment: Yes... I clicked the wrong button when adding my reply. And now, I see how to EDIT my "answer" but not how to change it to a "comment."

Comment: you will be able to comment if you reach 50, I added it as comment for you.